# Changing the Rank of a Matrix

Tags: matrix, fortran

I have a rank one array given by

```
COMPLEX(KIND = DBL),DIMENSION(DIMJ)::INITIALSTATE
```

How can I covert its rank to

```
DIMENSION(DIMJ,1)
```

so I can perform matrix operations on it -- transpose etc.

Note that the change is trivial. In both cases, we have a column vector. But Fortran won't trasnpose the array in the first form. Assume that `DIMJ` is an initialized integer.

Also, as obvious, I'd like the complex numbers to remain intact in the right positions after the manipulation.

Is it possible to perform such an operation in fortran?

Comment: *In both cases, we have a column vector.*  Not really.  In Fortran a rank-1 array is neither a column- nor a row-vector, or it is both a column- and a row-vector.  In cases such as calls to the intrinsic `matmul` a rank-1 array is treated as required (as either a column or a row) to make it conformable for matrix multiplication with the other argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [broadcast an array to different shape (adding "fake" dimensions)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669006/broadcast-an-array-to-different-shape-adding-fake-dimensions)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a temporary read-only version of the array, you can always use `RESHAPE`:

```
TRANSPOSEDSTATE = transpose(reshape(INITIALSTATE, (/ DIMJ, 1 /)))
```

But this doesn't change the shape of the `INITIALSTATE` variable. Also, that is the same as

```
TRANSPOSEDSTATE = reshape(INITIALSTATE, (/ 1, DIMJ /))
```

no `transpose` needed.

Comment: Great. `Transpose` works for complex arrays as well, right? That is, it both transposes the array and complex conjugates the elements in the array?

Comment: Quite frankly, I don't know. I'd just try it out myself.

Comment: @JunaidAftab, `transpose` does nothing to the values (other than their locations): there is no special treatment for complex values against any other argument.

Comment: @francescalus so, how take the complex conjugate transpose of a column vector in fortran?

Comment: @JunaidAftab `conjg(transpose(Z))`, or using some external library.