# Linear Indexing of Multi-Dimension Arrays in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran

Let A be a multi-dimensional array of DIMENSION(m,n,p). Is linear indexing of A (using a single index) allowed in Fortran? If so, what is correspondence between the linear index and the multi-dimensional index?

In other words, is A(i) allowed, and which element does A(i) correspond to (in which order are the dimensions traversed)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.obliquity.com/computer/fortran/array.html explains that arrays are stored in "column-major" form, so that the left most index changes the most quickly, followed by the second to leftmost, etc. (this is the opposite of C, I believe). It seems quite unwise to try to index a multidimensional array as though it were one-dimensional, but as the above-linked page explains, your compiler will produce code that does just that (and is therefore very fast) *as long as you nest your loops in the right order*.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a 3D array to a function or subroutine as if it were a 1D array, as shown in the code below. I don't recommend using this feature, but you will see it in pre-Fortran 90 code.

```
program xarray
implicit none
! demonstrate storage association
integer, parameter :: n1 = 2, n2 = 4, n3 = 3
integer :: i1,i2,i3,arr(n1,n2,n3)
forall (i1=1:n1,i2=1:n2,i3=1:n3) arr(i1,i2,i3) = i1 + 10*i2 + 100*i3
print*,"arr =",arr
! output: arr = 111 112 121 122 131 132 141 142 211 212 221 222 231 232 241 242 311 312 321 322 331 332 341 342
call print_array(arr,n1*n2*n3)
end program xarray

subroutine print_array(arr,n)
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: arr(n)
integer, intent(in) :: n
print*,"arr(1), arr(n) =",arr(1),arr(n)
! output: arr(1), arr(n) = 111 342
end subroutine print_array
```

Comment: Off topic question: is subroutine print_array(arr,n) missing: 
integer, intent(in) :: n ?

Comment: This actually is directly-related to another question I had - could you take a look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472907/resizing-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-when-passed

Comment: I added implicit none and the declaration of n, although it was not required.

Comment: Oh that's right. It's only required if implicit none is used. Thanks Fortranner.

Answer (score 3):

For the array declared `dimension A(m,n,p)` it isn't allowed to reference like `A(i)`.  However, the linear indexing, the so-called *array element order* is an important concept.  As stated in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24472228/3157076) the left-most index is the most rapidly varying.  `A(1,1,1)` comes immediately before `A(2,1,1)`, ..., `A(1,2,1)`, etc.

The array element order becomes useful because of various associations, and the like.  For example - not that I would recommend them except with real need - `equivalence` and argument association with an assumed-size array allow much the same thing.

As a more modern feature, one can have [pointer bounds remapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5406261).  And, of course, with a copy, the `reshape` intrinsic.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the following possibility, even though I've never used it, since I find it confusing. Someone ([Nek5000](https://nek5000.mcs.anl.gov/files/2015/09/NEK_doc.pdf), see page 22) claims it's faster.

> ```
> do i=1,nx1*ny1*nz1*nelv
>     u(i,1,1,1) = vx(i,1,1,1)
> enddo
> ```
>
> which is equivalent but superior (WHY?) to:
>
> ```
> do e=1,nelv
>     do k=1,nz1
>         do j=1,ny1
>             do i=1,nx1
>                 u(i,j,k,e) = vx(i,j,k,e)
>             enddo
>         enddo
>     enddo
> enddo
> ```
>
> which is equivalent but vastly superior (WHY?) to:
>
> ```
> do i=1,nx1
>     do j=1,ny1
>         do k=1,nz1
>             do e=1,nelv
>                 u(i,j,k,e) = vx(i,j,k,e)
>             enddo
>         enddo
>     enddo
> enddo
> ```