# unable to compile and load program from earlier post "changing array dimensions in fortran"

Tags: fortran

In

[changing array dimensions in fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406016/changing-array-dimensions-in-fortran/19898332#19898332)

there is a program by Lance Larsen:

```
program arrayresize
  implicit none
  integer, allocatable :: array1(:)
  integer, pointer :: array2(:,:)

  ! allocate and initialize array1
  allocate(array1(6))
  array1 = (/1,2,3,4,5,6/)

  ! This starts out initialized to 2
  print *, 'array1(2) = ', array1(2)

  ! Point array2 to same data as array1. The shape of array2
  ! is passed in as an array of intergers because C_F_POINTER
  ! uses and array of intergers as a SIZE parameter.
  array2 => getArray(array1, (/2,3/))

  ! Change the value at array2(2,1) (same as array1(2))
  array2(2,1) = 5

  ! Show that data in array1(2) was modified by changing
  ! array2(2,1)
  print *, 'array(2,1) = array1(2) = ', array1(2)

contains

  function getArray(array, shape_) result(aptr)
    use iso_c_binding, only: C_LOC, C_F_POINTER
    ! Pass in the array as an array of fixed size so that there
    ! is no array descriptor associated with it. This means we
    ! can get a pointer to the location of the data using C_LOC
    integer, target :: array(1)
    integer :: shape_(:)
    integer, pointer :: aptr(:,:)

    ! Use C_LOC to get the start location of the array data, and
    ! use C_F_POINTER to turn this into a fortran pointer (aptr).
    ! Note that we need to specify the shape of the pointer using an
    ! integer array.
    call C_F_POINTER(C_LOC(array), aptr, shape_)
  end function
end program
```

My op.system is:

```
@ uname -a
HP-UX rx2800 B.11.31 U ia64
```

and I'm using HP Fortran 90 Compiler and associated products (S800) for HP-UX 11.31.

I put the above program into `h.f`, and then

```
@ f90 +DD64 -o ./h.out h.f
```

which produces the following error message:

```
47 Lines Compiled
ld: Unsatisfied symbol "iso_c_binding$c_loc_array_1d_int4" in file h.o
ld: Unsatisfied symbol "iso_c_binding$c_f_pointer_array_2d_4s_int4" in file h.o
2 errors.
```

Is there a way to "satisfy" these symbols?

I have no idea. Maybe load some library?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Please not that `f90` is more a generic name to invoke a compiler than being "precise" (like `ifort`, `nagfor` or `gfortran`). We can probably guess from HP-UX and the style of compiler options/messages, but extra detail will always help - particularly including version numbers we can't guess.

Comment: B3909DB          B.11.31.13        HP Fortran 90 Compiler and associated products (S800) for HP-UX 11.31

Comment: The link errors you get relate to the compiler's own [runtime library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66870874/3157076). You'll need someone with more experience of that compiler than I have to tell you why the linker isn't finding things, and how to fix it.

Comment: However, please be aware that the example you are trying to use isn't a very good way to address your problem about changing array shapes. Not only isn't it valid Fortran, but it's also horribly over-complicated. You really want to use the pointer bounds remapping of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5406261/3157076).

Comment: @ f90 +DD64 -o ./janneb.out janneb.f
janneb.f
   program PTRTEST
        b (1:n, 1:n) => a
        ^
Error 805 at (7:janneb.f) : This pointer and the target must have the same type, type parameters and rank

1 Error
f90: error 213: Errors detected, no link.

Comment: Perhaps that compiler is sufficiently ancient that it doesn't support Fortran 2003 fully. Do you have access to other Fortran compilers? If you have, you may save yourself a lot of pain in the longer term than being restricted to a "Fortran 90" compiler which misses features from a language more than 20 years old.

Comment: In fact, my original problem: Using ONE malloc() I can allocate all of available physical memory to ONE arrayA. If, instead, I make TWO malloc() calls to allocate memory first to ArrayB and then to arrayC, then the total memory that can be allocated to ArrayB&C is only about  half!! of available memory. I wanted to circumvent this problem by first allocating all available physical memory to arrayA, and then "equivalence" parts of it to arrayB&C. I can not switch to some other compiler. All the same, I appreciate your help!